# Java JAX-WS service returning SOAP fault when queried by Perl's SOAP::Lite module

Tags: java, perl, soap, jax-ws

I have a simple Java service to get the current time.

I wrote a Perl client to access it.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use SOAP::Lite;
my $url = 'http://127.0.0.1:9876/ts?wsdl';
my $service = SOAP::Lite->service($url)->soapversion('1.1');

print "\nCurrent time is: ", $service->getTimeAsString();
print "\nElapsed milliseconds from the epoch: ", $service->getTimeAsElapsed();
```

As soon as the client makes the call (also on same machine) the service logs the exception below and a SOAP fault is returned to the client instead of the expected response.

```
Nov 05, 2011 11:20:34 AM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$Http Toolkit handle
SEVERE: Couldn't create SOAP message. Expecting Envelope in namespace http://sch
emas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/, but got http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.protocol.soap.VersionMismatchException: Couldn't create
SOAP message. Expecting Envelope in namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/en
velope/, but got http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCod ec.java:167)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCod ec.java:292)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCod ec.java:118)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:343)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.decodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:321)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$400(HttpAdapter.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:576)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handleExchange(WSHttpHandler.java:95)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handle(WSHttpHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)
at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:80)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:665)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:637)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but for everyone else that is having this issue, the problem is that SOAP::Lite is blindly importing the namespaces from the WSDL file and overwriting its own based on the prefixes used there, including the namespace it uses to send the SOAP Envelope itself.

The solution is to make it use a different namespace prefix for the SOAP Envelope, using the envprefix method. For example:

`my $service = SOAP::Lite->service($url)->soapversion('1.1')->envprefix('S');`

Answer (score 0):

Your client Python is sending the XML in a different format that the expected by your Java Web Service. In order to see what is really sending your client I suggest that you use the following tool

http://code.google.com/p/tcpmon/

It will let you check the XML sended and modify it if you want. Here is a tutorial about how to use TcpMon

http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/tcpmontutorial.html